# Estimator for $\theta$ on $U[0,\theta]$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation

Consider $\theta^\ast = X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}$. I have the following questions:

> Is $\theta^\ast$ unbiased?

I would say so. I need to show that $\mathbb E[\theta^\ast] = \mathbb E[X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}] = \theta$. The expectation of $\mathbb E[X_{(n)}]$ is

\begin{align*}
F_{X_{n}}(x) &= \mathbb P(X_{(n)}\leqslant x)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_{(1)}\leqslant x,\dots, X_{(n)}\leqslant x)\\
&= \left(\frac x\theta\right)^n\\
f_{X_{(n)}}(x) &= F'_{X_{(n)}}(x)\\
&=n\theta^{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
\mathbb E[X_{(n)}] &= \int\limits_0^\theta xf_{X_{(n)}}(x)\\
&=\frac {n}{n+1}\theta.
\end{align*}

The expectation of $\mathbb E[X_{(1)}]$ is
\begin{align*}
F_{X_{(1)}}(x) &= 1-[1-F_{X}]^n\\
&=1-[1-\frac x\theta ]^n\\
f_{X_{(1)}}(x)&= F'_{X_{(1)}}(x)\\
&=n\theta^{-1} \left(1-\frac x \theta\right)^{n-1}\\
\mathbb E[X_{(1)}] &= \int\limits_{0}^\theta xf_{X_{(1)}}(x)\\
&=\frac 1{n+1}\theta.
\end{align*}
And therefore we have $$\mathbb E[X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}] = \frac{n}{n+1}\theta + \frac1 {n+1}\theta = \theta.$$

> Is $\theta^\ast$ unbiased consistent?

I need to show that $\mathbb P(|\theta-\theta^\ast|\geqslant \varepsilon)\to0$ for all $\varepsilon >0, n\to\infty$. I am not sure how to do this or even if it is true. I believe I have to use some *central limit theorem*.

Comment: I didn't check the calculations but instead of the annoying computations using densities you can use the fact that for any non-negative random variable $X$ we have that $\operatorname{E}[X]=\int_{[0,\infty )}\Pr [X>t]\,d t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see that indeed $\Pr [|X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}-\theta |\geqslant \epsilon ]\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty $ it is enough to show that $X_{(1)}\to 0$ and $X_{(n)}\to \theta $ in probability, because

$$
\Pr [|X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}-\theta |\geqslant \epsilon ]\leqslant \Pr [|X_{(1)}|\geqslant \epsilon /2]+\Pr [|X_{(n)}-\theta |\geqslant \epsilon /2]
$$

Comment: Thank you @Masacroso!